# How to determine a UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer's frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uiedgeinsets

I'm trying to figure out what the actual point values are when you specify UIRectEdgeRight, etc. when you set up a UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer.

It appears I cannot simply NSLog anything about the UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer, as there's no property to log on such a recognizer.

I basically am trying to determine when this recognizer will and wont trigger, as I want to place another recognizer away from this edge accordingly.

Thank you for any help/tips provided

```
/*! This subclass of UIPanGestureRecognizer only recognizes if the user slides their finger
in from the bezel on the specified edge. */

NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0) @interface UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer : UIPanGestureRecognizer

@property (readwrite, nonatomic, assign) UIRectEdge edges; //< The edges on which this gesture recognizes, relative to the current interface orientation

@end
```

Comment: As you shown, UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer is a subclass of UIPanGestureRecognizer. So properties available in UIPanGestureRecognizer will still be available to its subclasses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out by trial and error, that a UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer will trigger 20 pts from its respective edge.